# Brand New Monitor Won't Get Input From Computer

Tags: dell-poweredge

I have an old Dell 2350. I found a HD a few months ago and plugged it in and it booted up. So I just purchased a monitor and plugged it in, and put the HD inside and connected the two connections (Bus, and a four pronged connector) and no signal is being sent to monitor.

is this a monitor issue or the HD is just dead? HD is spinning. CPU is turned on :) Yet no signal.. any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.
RAM was not in all the way.